# Ios Grouped Barchart, do not paint zero or empty values

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I don't want to dislay  the zeros on my group bar chart

I am using ios charts library, is there any way I can get rid of the zeros?
You can check the image here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_KV3MPKH8RYWRQV0lhbU43VVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So what you want means if 0 value than you have to remove that bar or something else ?

Comment: Yes if I have 0 value then I dont want to display the 0 label over there. Only if the vaue is greater than 0 I need to display label.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement here you can use Formatter Delegate `IChartValueFormatter` and return nil value to that delegate method.

**Check this code :**

**1st**-Confirm Protocol for value formatter :

```
@interface ViewController ()<IChartValueFormatter>
```

**2nd**-Assign Delegate to Value Formatter :

```
BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:arrVals1];
set1.valueFormatter = self;
```

**3rd**-Implement Value Formatter method:

```
#pragma mark - IChartValueFormatter

- (NSString * _Nonnull)stringForValue:(double)value entry:(ChartDataEntry * _Nonnull)entry dataSetIndex:(NSInteger)dataSetIndex viewPortHandler:(ChartViewPortHandler * _Nullable)viewPortHandler{

    if (value>0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f",value];
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

return nil while value is less than 0.

Hope this will helps.